# gcloud compute ssh --command flag not working

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am using google's compute ssh command from compute engine's vm1 to connect another project's vm2. The problem occur when i try to connect with --command flag. The shell command is not executed but ssh connection is established. However i can see the bash command in the processes of vm2 as pid =xxxx 'bash -c sudo su && service nginx stop && source /home/x/bin/activate && python example.py'
When i terminated the ssh command from vm1, the bash command immediately starts on vm2. I could not figure it out what cause this problem.

```
sudo gcloud compute ssh --project=project_name vm_name --zone=zone --command='sudo su && service nginx stop && source /home/x/bin/activate && python example.py'
```

OS: ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Hi zeo, as I know command should look like:
`sudo gcloud compute ssh --project project_name vm_name --zone zone --command 'sudo su && service nginx stop && source /home/x/bin/activate && python example.py'`
Try to execute this command without `=` character

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrii but still not working until i terminate ssh connection.

Comment: Remove `sudo su` and prefix necessary commands with `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That command set won't work.  You're approaching it as if you were the one running the commands inside a terminal, in which case:

- `sudo su` (would get you a root shell and all subsequent commands would run as root)
- `service nginx stop` (you're root)
- `source /home/x/bin/activate` (you're root)
- `python example.py` (you're root)

When you try to chain your commands with `&&`, it runs the next command after the first one worked and all the commands are actually being run as you:

- `sudo su` (run as you, when this exits successfully, trigger next command)
- `service nginx stop` (as you)
- etc (as you)

So what ends up happening is you get a root shell and then nothing.  Unless that exits (cleanly), you won't run the next command in the chain and so you're waiting, because the root shell is also waiting.  As @DazWilkin mentioned above, what you should actually be doing is removing the `sudo su` (you don't need a root shell, you can't do anything in there anyway) and preface your other commands with `sudo` instead so that they are each run with elevated perms.